# How can I prove that the DE $y'=y^\alpha$ has infinitely many solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show that the DE $y'=y^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is a constant with $0<\alpha<1$, has infinitely many solutions passing through the point $(0,0)$.
Also I need four of such solutions.
Thank you for your help!
Klara

Comment: This smells like homework. But *you*, do you have any idea?

Comment: I think that considering "the solution at a point 'c' " is equivalent to considering a boundary value problem which always have a unique solution but the trivial or singular solution(if exist).
Also, your problem (considering the condition (0,0)) is a BV. I could not see what is the matter of being puzzled.

Comment: If we omit the option of solutions passing through $(0,0)$, what would happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here how you can proceed. First note that $y=0$ is a solution. Next, you use integration to get
$$
\int_0^y\frac{dy}{y^{\alpha}}=t+C_1.
$$
Note that on the left hand side you have an improper integral which converges if $0<\alpha<1$ -- this is the reason the solutions are not unique at the point $(0,0)$. Assuming that $0<\alpha<1$ you get
$$
y=K(t-C)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
$$ 
also a solution to your equation. Here $K$ is a constant which depends on $\alpha$.

Here is a first example of a solution
$$
y_1(t)=\begin{cases}
0&t<0,\\
Kt^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}&t\geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The only thing you need to check that it has a continuous derivative at $t=0$, which can be checked by direct calculation.

Generalizing, any function of the form
$$
y_1(t)=\begin{cases}
0&t<C,\\
K(t-C)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}&t\geq C.
\end{cases}
$$
is a solution (you need to check the derivative at $t=C$) and they all pass through $(0,0)$ if $C>0$.

Comment: @ artem thank you, this is exactly the solution my professor put on the board, I wander why is it important that y_1 should have an continous derivative at C and not only a lets say continuous solution at c? Thank you again.

Comment: @Klara There should be a continuous derivative at $C$ because otherwise this function would not be a solution (by definition, a solution is a function which you can plug in into your equation and get an identity).

Comment: @Artem In the total solution,  $$
y_1(t)=\begin{cases}
0&t<0,\\
Kt^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}&t\geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$ How/why did you write the first part, I understand the second part. Please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$ y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = y^{\alpha}, \ y(0)=0, \ 0<\alpha<1$$
From this we can start 
\begin{align}
 \frac{dy}{dx} &= y^{\alpha}
\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{  y^{\alpha}} dy &= dx
\\ \Leftrightarrow \int \frac{1}{  y^{\alpha}} dy &= \int 1 dx
\end{align}
Since this really does smell like homework like Siminore said, you should try from this point by your own. Remember the integration constant and fit that with the initial condition $y(0)=0$.

Edit: Okay if this isn't HW I shall continue.

Taking the above we get:
\begin{align}
  \int \frac{1}{  y^{\alpha}} dy &= \int 1 dx
\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{y^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}+c &=x \,  \text{  as } \, 0<\alpha<1
\\ \Leftrightarrow y^{1-\alpha}&=(x-c)\cdot(1-\alpha)
\\ \Leftrightarrow y &= ((x-c)\cdot(1-\alpha))^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{align}

Now we also have to check whether our initial condition is fulfilled.
$$ y(0) =((0-c)\cdot(1-\alpha))^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}=0$$
only for $c=0$, so
$$ y(x) = (x\cdot(1-\alpha))^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} $$
is the unique solution of the above ODE.

Edit: It is not the unique solution, since $y(t)=0 \ \forall t$ also solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, This is not HW.I know how to do what you wrote upstairs. I had this on an prior exam and now I need to study the exams for possible similar problem in final and since I did not do it right to begin with, I posted it here for help.

Comment: This DE does have infinite number of solutions.My professor said that the combination of these two solutions at point c is a solutions as well. And we need to show that this cmobination solution is differentiable at c and since c can have any value in the real line then there are infinite number of solutions possible. Thank you!

Comment: "_and that the combination of these two solutions at point c is a solutions as well_"
Which two solutions to you mean? I am not sure whether I am missing something here. Maybe somebody can check my answer?

Comment: hm and obvious $y(t)=0 \forall t$ is a solution as well.

Comment: yes the y=0 is the other one, but why showing that  the combined solution is just continuous at c is not enough?

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand your question. And having two solutions isn't the same as having infinite solution.
And finally I am no longer sure whether my answer is correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6651/discussion-between-macydanim-and-klara)