# Non Uniqueness - ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE: $x'[t]=\left|x\right|^{p/q}$, $p,q > 0$, and share no common factors. Can someone prove that for the initial condition $x[0]=0$ and $p < q$, there are an infinite number of solutions. And if $p > q$, there is a unique solution.

Cheers

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure. I've calculated the solutions for two domains [x<0, x>0]. I don't know how to edit here, so I'll use a poor notation, sorry: For [x<0], dx/[x^(p/q)]= -dt; solving I've got: x(t)={-t*[q/(q-p)]}^[(q-p)/q]. For [x>0], it's the same solution, only changing -t for t, in the answer. Then I got stuck. Thank you

Comment: The question is the same as that in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252257/differential-equation-has-infinitely-many-solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you have the right idea, but you need to do the calculation a with a little bit more care, and keep track of the constants of integration.

You're correct to separate variables, so we have

$$
\int x^{-p/q} dx = t + C \\
\frac{q}{q-p}x^{\frac{q-p}{q}} = t + C \\
x = K\left(t + C \right)^\frac{q}{q-p}
$$
where $K$ is some constant determined by $q$ and $p$, but $C$ hasn't had any restrictions placed on it yet.

Now, the thing to notice about all of these functions, if $p<q$ is that, at $t = -C$, you have $x = 0$ and $x' = 0$ (verify this both mathematically, and for intuition, graphically (w/ e.g. $x = t^{3/2}$)). So, if we translate the 'basic' solution $x = K t^\frac{q}{q-p}$ to the right, it will still be a solution of the IVP, and the derivative will even still be continuous! Specifically,

$$
x =
\begin{cases} 
0 &: 0 \leq t < C, \\
K\left(t - C \right)^\frac{q}{q-p} &: t > C
\end{cases}
$$

will be a solution for every $C > 0$.

To see why there is a unique solution in the other case, $p>q$, appeal to the broader theory of existence and uniqueness for ODEs. You should know something about Lipschitz functions, maybe?

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I guess the mistake i did was using the initial condition to find C. Then x[0]=0 implies C=0. But I've not seen that when t= -C, the function is also 0. Then C is not well defined by the Initial condition; and there are an infinite number of solutions, shown by your demonstration. I will look further for the case p>q, using you tip. Cheers