# Show there are infinitely many distinct maximal solutions of $\frac{dx}{dt} = (3/2)x^{1/3}$ that pass through the point $(t_0,0)$

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = (3/2)x^{1/3}$$

1. Solve
2. Show that given any point $(t_0,0)$ on the $t$-axis, there are infinitely many distinct maximal solutions that pass through the point.

---

We are given:

---

> **Definition**: Let $x = x(t)$. A **solution of the first order ODE** $x' = f(t,x)$, where $f$ is defined on some domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $D$ is open and connected, is a differentiable function $\varphi$ on some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t.
>
> 1. $(t, \varphi(t)) \in D \ \forall t \in I$
> 2. $\varphi'(t) = f(t, \varphi(t)) \ \forall t \in I$

---

> **Existence Theorem**: If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $(\tau, \xi) \in D$, then $\exists$ a solution $\varphi$ of $x' = f(t,x)$ defined on some interval $I$ s.t. $\tau \in I$ and $\varphi(\tau) = \xi$

---

> **Uniqueness Theorem**: If $f$ and $f_x$ are continuous on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $(\tau, \xi) \in D$, then there exists a unique maximal solution $\varphi$ of $x' = f(t,x)$ defined on some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t. $\tau \in I$ and $\varphi(\tau) = \xi$

---

What I tried:

1. Choose $D = [-K, \infty) \times \mathbb R$. Is that open and connected?

$x_1(t) = \sqrt{(t+K)^3}$, $t \ge - K$,

$x_2(t) = -\sqrt{(t+K)^3}$, $t \ge - K$

$x_3(t) = 0, t \in \mathbb R$

Is that right?

2. I got

$x_1(t) = \sqrt{(t-t_0)^3}$, $t \color{red}{>} t_0$,

$x_2(t) = -\sqrt{(t-t_0)^3}$, $t \color{red}{>} t_0$

$x_3(t) = 0, t \in \mathbb R$

$$f(t,x) = (3/2)x^{1/3}$$

$$f_x(t,x) = (1/2)x^{-2/3}$$

Choose $D = \color{red}{(}-K, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$. Then

$(t_0, 0) \notin D$ :(

Choose $D = \color{red}{(}-K, \infty) \times (-\infty, 0)$. Then

$(t_0, 0) \notin D$ :(

Choose $D = \mathbb R \times (-\infty, 0)$. Then

$(t_0, 0) \notin D$ :(

Choose $D = \mathbb R \times (0, \infty)$. Then

$(t_0, 0) \notin D$ :(

Please suggest alternate D's or other ways I can approach this problem.

---

Actually, I'm not quite sure I understand the problem.

Given a point say $(5,0)$, it seems that the two distinct maximal solutions that pass through such point are:

$x_1(t) = \sqrt{(t-5)^3}$, $t \color{red}{>} 5$,

$x_2(t) = -\sqrt{(t-5)^3}$, $t \color{red}{>} 5$

$x_3(t) = 0, t \in \mathbb R$

Where are the remaining $\infty - 3$ ? :|

Comment: Hint: it seems that $x(t)=0$ is a solution.

Comment: What is important is the solution, not the way to find it. Do try to use my hint to produce new solutions.

Comment: @Jonas Never mind. realised what was wrong with my comment. thanks, but I don't see how this helps. What are the remaining $\infty - 3$ solutions?

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252257/how-can-i-prove-that-the-de-y-y-alpha-has-infinitely-many-solutions/253070#253070)

Comment: @Artem Thanks! ^-^

Comment: @Jonas Added answer!

Comment: I'm not sure why you were voted down, this was much more well formatted than lots I see..

Comment: @DaveNine Thanks. ^-^ It might have something to do with someone or some people who has or have been downvoting me. I suspect that someone or one of those people is username 'Did'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link given by Artem:

$$x(t) = 0 \times 1_{t < K} + (t-K)^{3/2} \times 1_{t \ge K}$$

1. is a solution (check that $\lim_{t \to K} x'(t)$ exists)
2. passes through $(t_0,0)$ for $K \ge t_0$