# Why, visually, are ODEs not unique without (roughly) Lipschitz coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ Consider the ODE
$$\begin{cases}
        y'(t) = f(t, y(t)) \quad \\
        y(t_0) = y_0 \end{cases}$$
with $f: I \times U \to \R^n$, $t_0 \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$ an open interval and $y_0 \in U \subset \R^n$ an open domain.

By the local version of the [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) (also called Cauchy-Lipschitz) Theorem, if $f$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz continuous in the second variable, a unique solution exists on a maximal interval of existence $t_0 \in I_{\max} \subset I$.

In general, the Lipschitz continuity is roughly also necessary for uniqueness (albeit slightly more moderate conditions like the [Osgood Criterion](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Osgood_criterion) exist), as illustrated by the the example
$$\begin{cases}
        y'(t) = |y(t)|^{\alpha} \quad \\
        y(0) = 0 \end{cases}$$
for $0 < \alpha < 1$. This ODE has [infinitely many solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252257/how-can-i-prove-that-the-de-y-y-alpha-has-infinitely-many-solutions?noredirect=1&lq=1) of the form $$y_C(t)=\begin{cases}
0,&t<C, \quad \\
(1- \alpha)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} (t-C)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}, &t\geq C.
\end{cases}$$
for $C \in [0, \infty]$ arbitrary.

> **Question.** Why does the lacking Lipschitz continuity / Osgood condition allow for this example? What is the visual or intuitive reason that an $0<\alpha < 1$-Hölder continuous $f$ (maybe in general) allows in for multiple solutions as opposed to a Lipschitz one?

---

Two further remarks:

- In the above [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252257/how-can-i-prove-that-the-de-y-y-alpha-has-infinitely-many-solutions?noredirect=1&lq=1) it is emphasized that for this example the Osgood condition is violated.
- (Lastly, there is a "dual" result: For $\alpha > 1$, clearly local existence and uniqueness holds, but for  $y(0) \neq 0$ the solution blows up in finite time by self-reinforcing growth due to the $\alpha > 1$ exponent.)